# My SQL Trigger Before Update

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I apologise if this question has been asked a million times before!

So I am trying to create a trigger on a table when an employee is assigned a task the pick_date is updated to show this. It only should update the date field if its null. The order number, employee and order_pick_date are all on the same table.

I have the following trigger but I can't seem to get it to run.

```
CREATE TRIGGER pickDate BEFORE UPDATE
ON order_master
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE order_master SET NEW.order_pick_date = IFNULL(SYSDATE(),) WHERE  order_master.order_no = old.order_no
END;
```

Comment: What errors do you get? For start - you `IFNULL` syntax is wrong: there's no second parameter.

Comment: Tried without the IFNULL and get ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
 for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `before update` trigger is fine.  You just do not want to do an `update`.  Simply set the value on the `new` record:

```
CREATE TRIGGER pickDate BEFORE UPDATE
ON order_master
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.order_pick_date = COALESCE(old.order_pick_date, now()) ;
END;
```

There are some other issues (such as `getdate()` being SQL Server syntax), but I think this is what you intend.

Comment: So I have tried the below:
DELIMETER //
CREATE TRIGGER pickDate BEFORE UPDATE
ON order_master
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    SET NEW.order_pick_date = COALESCE(old.order_pick_date, now()) ;
END//
DELIMTER;

And I Get:
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
 for the right syntax to use near 'END//

Any Idea why?

Comment: Thanks for the assistance Gordon I will remember that for the future. :)